# Manipular un array de javascript en PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Una consulta:

Tengo un array llamado arrayFinal en javascript de esta manera:

```
var arrayFinal = [];

for(var i = 0; i < (tituloArray.length); i++){

    arrayFinal[i] = {titulo : tituloArray[i], cantidad : cantidadArray[i], valorItem : valorItemArray[i], idProducto : idProductoArray[i]}

}
```

La pregunta es: ¿Cuál es la mejor manera para que ese array sea visible en un archivo PHP y poder manipularlo?

Comment: Podrias usar Ajax.

Comment: @alanfcm si, pense en ello. Podrias darme un ejemplo? Lo que busco es que un archivo php lo tenga siempre presente para poder luego usarlo. Calculo que seria con metodo POST. O me equivoco?

Comment: El codigo PHP está en el mismo archivo que ese array o se encuentra situado en otro al que tienes que llamar? Lo optimo en mi opninion, que este en otro, y que hagas una llamada enviando el array como json por ejemplo.

Comment: @GDP exacto, se encuentra en otro archivo. Podrías darme un ejemplo de como dices? Teniendo en cuenta que está en otro archivo.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function nombreFuncion(){

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    clean = new XMLHttpRequest();
 
  }
  else{
    clean = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  clean.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if (clean.readyState  == 4 && clean.status == 200) {

  
  }

}

  clean.open('GET','nombreDeTuArchivoPHP.php?variable='+var1,true);
  clean.send();


}
```

Yo utilizo javascript puro para manejar AJAX y mando mis variables Javascript a PHP con GET, tu mandarias tu arreglo en la variable var1, espero te sirva esto, cualquier duda hazla saber.